# How to put many Model classes together in one Module to use in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

In rails i have a lot of tables and need to define a lot of Model classes to use for controller, but i want to put all the model classes into one module file, and then make controller to use the model class in the module, but i don't know how to do it.

Could someone give me help on the problem? Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app/models/widgets/blue_widget.rb
class Widgets::BlueWidget < ActiveRecord::Base
  // etc.
end

app/controllers/blue_widget_controller.rb
def index
  @widgets = Widgets::BlueWidget.all
end
```

You can also namespace the controllers.

Edit:

```
lib/widgets.rb
module Widgets
  class BlueWidget
  end

  class RedWidget
  end
end

controller:
require 'lib/widgets'
def index
  @widgets = Widgets::BlueWidget.all
end
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: i mean there are a lot of models defined in one module, how to use each model class of the module in rails controller. your answer seems not to for my question. am i clear?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean, does that work? i will try as you said. if you experienced please tell me, thank you very much.

Comment: the way doesn't work. "NameError (uninitialized constant Rcm::GlobalConfigs):"

Comment: That is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate models directly in subdirectorys and get them im modules:

```
rails g model user/likes name:string like:boolean
```

and you will get your generated files.

The generated model would be in app/models/user/likes.rb

```
class User::Likes < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```